# Is there a `purge` command in Debian/Ubuntu similar to the purge in Mac OS X?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, debian

Mac OS X has a pretty cool tool called [`purge`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/purge.8.html).

You run it at the command line and it frees up all available memory - slowing your system to a halt in the process.

I often free up 2GB of memory or more after running it.

Is this available for Debian/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Edited 8/19/12 to add explanation on drop_caches:

**Explanation on `drop_caches`**

Since Kernel 2.6.16, you can control how cache behaves, there are four possible “positions” for the switch.

0 -> Will give the Kernel full control to the cache memory 1 -> Will free the page cache 2 -> Will free dentries and inodes 3 -> Will free dentries and inodes as well as page cache

So, just enter those values to the file `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, with `echo`, and as root:

```
sync; echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

or

```
sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

or

```
sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

or

```
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
```

Comment: The OP is asking about purging _memory_, not installed packages.